# Nodejs Express sendStatus error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The web app uses express for the server, nodejs as the language, mongodb as the database and mongoose as the wrapper. Express is running a server at port 3000 and I'm trying to implement a basic CRUD for a collection.

I've used restify before and normally doing a res.send(406, "err - body"); doesn't cause any issues however I can't seem to figure it out with express.

Looking at express' documentation, res.status(404).send('Bad Request'); is how you send a status code with a custom message back. It works when there's some sort of invalid input but when I try to save to mongodb

```
newSchema.save(function(err){ 
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send('error saving');
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
});
```

and call res.sendStats(200); it gives me the error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. When using a httprequester, the error is 404 and Cannot POST /user/create.

Comment: I had a similar problem but it was because I did res.sendStatus(404).json('myjson') instead of res.status(404).json('myjson').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not a good idea to copy restify code into express. I had a next(); which doesn't work with express or it does but as of right now, I don't need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending another response afterwards? Ie... maybe you're doing something like:

```
if (!err){
    res.send()
}
```

wherever the function is called (or after the code you pasted). And obviously, this could be the source of your error, since you'd be sending two separate responses.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `res.sendStatus()`, I changed to  `res.send()`, and it works beautifully.